# JqueryMobile Ajax Loop

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a bit of ajax that grabs some content from my website and injects it into the phonegap application. I noticed this page is extremely choppy when I scroll and I wonder if it's because I have Ajax code that constantly wrongs in the background? Is there a way to stop my ajax after it fetches the content. Or is there something else that is slowing this page. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

https://gist.github.com/2408732

Comment: Do you do your ajax call in a loop, or do you have it on an interval? You might want to try something like: setInterval(function () { yourAjaxCall(); }, 5000);

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm not sure. This is my first run with Ajax. I don't think it's in a loop, but I wasn't sure if that ajax call just stays open and constantly running until I close it?

Comment: It is possible you are loading too much into a mobile device. Try a smaller json request set than the 1200 liner you are calling from.

Comment: @wachpwnski You should post that as an answer. That is definitely too much information for most mobile devices today.

Comment: Is there a different way to do this? Looks like I need all of the info I'm pulling. I was able to take out a few things but in general I need most of it.

Comment: It also seems that it's slow even after the json loads. Could it be that I have too many html elements? Would that slow mobile down?

Comment: Just for kick I limited the json to just 1 field and it's still super slow when scrolling on IOS5. I'm pulling about 50 imgs, is this just too much for a mobile device to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this wasn't due to too many lines of json, but rather a scroll bug in JqueryMobile. Scrolling on a list of linked images caused me to have choppy performance. This post led me to my solution:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-jqm-touchscreen-list-scrolling-performance-stinks-and-what-to-do-about-it